# Use php to insert drop select form element

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to create a drop down box with php that pulls states from an array that is populated with state names. I have saved my file with the .php extension and have added code to attempt to create a drop down menu from my array that I am creating. For some reason, the drop down menu is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //create function to be called upon submission
            function verify(event) {
                var hasError = false;
                var check1=document.getElementById("saws").value;
                var check2=document.getElementById("pliers").value;
                var check3=document.getElementById("planers").value;
                var ok = [];
                ok[0] = check1.search(/^$|\d+/);
                ok[1] = check2.search(/^$|\d+/);
                ok[2] = check3.search(/^$|\d+/);
                for (i = 0; i < ok.length; i++) {
                    if (ok[i] !== 0) {
                        hasError = true;
                        alert("Invalid input.");
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                if (hasError) return false;
                else return true;
            }
        </script>
        <title>l6p2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Lab 6, part 2 </h1>
        <form action = "/formtest.php" method="post" onsubmit= "return verify(event)">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Saw</td>
                        <td>$15.99</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="saws" id="saws" size="2" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pliers</td>
                        <td>$12.99</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="pliers" id="pliers" size="2" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Planer</td>
                        <td>$79.99</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="planers" id="planers" size="2" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>
                <label> First Name:
                    <input type="text" name="fname" size ="30" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label> Last Name:
                    <input type="text" name="lname" size ="30" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label> Shipping Address:
                    <input type="text" name="address" size ="30" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label> City:
                    <input type="text" name="csz" size ="30" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <br />
                    <?php
                        $states = array('Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','California','Florida','Georgia');
                        echo '<label> State:';
                        echo '<select name="state">';
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($states); $i++) {
                            echo '<option>' . $states[$i] . '</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                        echo '</label>';
                    ?>

            </p>
            <h3>Payment Method</h3>
            <p>
                <label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="visa" checked = "checked" />
                    Visa
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="mc" />
                    Master Card
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="amex" />
                    American Express
                </label>
                <br />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="Submit" value="Submit Order" />
            </p>
        </form>

        <h3>Links</h3>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

This is the part that is not working correctly:

```
<?php
   $states = array('Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','California','Florida','Georgia');
    echo '<label> State:';
    echo '<select name="state">';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($states); $i++) {
       echo '<option>' . $states[$i] . '</option>';
    }
       echo '</select>';
       echo '</label>';
?>
```

Comment: what is not working correctly about it?

Comment: instead of displaying :"State: DROP DOWN WITH STATES HERE"

i get: "State:'; echo 'DROP DOWN THAT READS"'.$States[i].'"'; echo ''; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is the count on the loop, you need to know the array length, so try the sizeof($states) instead.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($states); $i++) {
```

Another thing: you had to put some value on the "option" to get that on the back-end side. Like this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$states[$i].'">' . $states[$i] . '</option>';
```

And the last: You don`t need to put the "select" inside the "label". You can use the "for" attribute on the label to reference the select id.
This is all the code:

```
<?php
     $states = array('Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','California','Florida','Georgia');
     echo '<label for="state"> State: </label>';
     echo '<select name="state" id="state">';
     for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($states); $i++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$states[$i].'">' . $states[$i] . 
        '</option>';
     }
     echo '</select>';
?>
```

Good luck. :)

Comment: `sizeof` is an alias of `count`, so that part makes no difference. Though using a `foreach` would work instead of using a counter.

Comment: Yeah, you right :). I think the problem is the value of the option indeed.

Comment: Unfortunately i end up with this displayed:

State:'; echo 'EMPTY DROP DOWN WITH SINGLE QUOTE AND PERIOD'; echo ''; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple foreach in this case:

```
foreach ($states as $state) {

    echo '<option value="'.$state.'">' . $state . '</option>';
}
```

Your array is basic and doesn't need any special magic to make it work.